# How to zoom to route loaded from cache - Skobbler Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I was looking through the API, but I didn't noticed any delegate method that would be

```
-didFinishLoadinRouteFromCache
```

So, because of that, I have zooming method right after I load route from cache

```
    [_mapViewHolder addSubview:[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].mapView];
    [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] clearCurrentRoutes];
    [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] loadRouteFromCache:[Constants shared].routeID];
    [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].mapView clearAllAnnotations];
    [self createMapPins];

    [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] zoomToRouteWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] zoomToRouteWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

But even with calling zoomToRouteWithInsets twice, i still dong get to see an entire route as supposed.

Is there any other method which I should call in order to achieve zooming to route loaded from cache ?

Comment: We're looking into it - is your screen in landscape or portrait mode?

Comment: It's in the Portrait mode, without an option to switch to Landscape for now